# Inchoo Facebook Connect error for new accounts and login

Tags: facebook, magento, authentication, magento-1.7

Hello I've installed the Facebook connect extension of Inchoo for Magento.
The install went without errors. When i registered user login with his normal email and username and then connect his Facebook account he/she is able to login through Facebook in the future.

New users/registers always get the message : Facebook connection failed. This service is temperately unavailable.Try again later.

So there is an error with creating an account i think.
Anybody has a clue where to check and how to solve this?

Facebook Api / Secret are checked and correct.
Facebook redirect url is checked and correct.
I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above problem is solved by integrating another extension instead of the Facebook Connect from Inchoo. The one from inchoo isn't compatable with magenta 1.7.0.2.

I've used the one from Belvg.com. This one works perfectly.

Comment: can u please provide the valid downloadable link of free-fbconnect-belvg-extension.